# RecyclerView внутри NestedScrollView

Tags: java, recyclerview

Сделал горизонтальный `RecyclerView` внутри `NestedScrollView`. В итоге при запуске активности если `RecyclerView` не торчит на определенную высоту, то он сам делает чтобы торчал и скроллит `NestedScrollView`. Очень непонятное поведение, не смог найти ничего.

Вот так, когда описания мало (торчит на определенную высоту)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так, когда описания много (он сам скроллит, чтобы эта высота торчала)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код. Xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:contentScrim="@color/toolbar_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainbackdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/scrim_top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="19sp"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/nsv"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/info_text"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info_iv"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main_appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

@layout/info_text:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="ОПИСАНИЕ"
            style="@style/InfoTitle"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_description"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="СКРИНШОТЫ"
    style="@style/InfoTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/info_screens"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#9E413B"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Качество:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_quality"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Год выхода:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_year"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Перевод:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_translation"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Длительность:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_duration"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Страна:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_country"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Жанр:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_genre"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="В ролях:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_cast"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Режиссер:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_producer"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="СМОТРЕТЬ"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/toolbar_bg"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:minHeight="70dp"
        android:maxHeight="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_view"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/toolbar_bg"
        android:text="СКАЧАТЬ"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:minHeight="70dp"
        android:maxHeight="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_download"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
((NestedScrollView)(findViewById(R.id.nsv))).scrollTo(0,0); .//не катит
    scr = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.info_screens);
    scr.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    scr.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел. Нужно добавить

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

В ребенка `NestedScrollView`. [Оригинал ответа с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923948/recycleview-steals-focus-when-inside-a-nestedscrollview)

Comment: братан ты спас мой день.